# Why scraping a table from this url gets no content?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to get the table from following URL based on input data in the menu (for example year:1400). I used inspect method in Firefox browser to get preload data as well as request headers as a dictionary object. But after I sending post request I don't see the related table/diva tag in request content. Printing the related element gets nothing, while status code is 200. Please guide me to know how to modify my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://www.cbi.ir/PolicyRates/policyrates_fa.aspx"

data={
'__EVENTTARGET':'ctl00$ucBody$ucContent$ctl00$ddlYear',
'__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
'__LASTFOCUS':'',
'__VIEWSTATE':'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',
'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'4DAA8359',
'__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED':'',
'ctl00$ucHeader$txtQuickSearch':'',
'ctl00$ucBody$ucContent$ctl00$ddlYear':'1400',
}

headers={
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8',
'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Content-Length': '4544',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Cookie': 'TSPD_101=083d5cd761ab2800c1a9baa8dd7e2a40f5b72dbe748fb9e29f17911588a86656ac538a13a022bb30047ffa0afba445d7:083d5cd761ab2800c1a9baa8dd7e2a4',
}

req=requests.post(url,data=data , headers=headers, verify=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content,features="html.parser",)
table=soup.find("table",attrs={"class":"table table-hover table-responsive table-condensed table-bordered table-striped"})
div=soup.find("div",attrs={"id":"ctl00_ucBody_ucContent_ctl00_divRates"})
print(req.status_code)
print(table)
print(div)

200
None
None
```

Comment: The table is in your req, but highly convoluted and not making too much sense to me

Comment: Looking for Youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTiXxN3bD-Y&list=UUsFz0IGS9qFcwrh7a91juPg&index=35

Comment: Dear @Rivered ,@Dejene T None of the td and tr tags are found in table tag because I get an empty table tag, so converting it into a table is not possible, besides server is blocking requests too. Please see the answer given by Rivered.

Answer (score 1):

Your code on my PC returns weird response, looking a bit like javascript. I have checked and regenerated my browser post response, and that combined with your result produces the desired output:

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'f5_cspm': '1234',
    'TSPD_101': '083d5cd761ab2800d6610d314f7ca4a4b8a730600291be036c32ce2cd19d7671bbc035fed7caac6d7b3a12c46dd62a01:083d5cd761ab2800d6610d314f7ca4a4b8a730600291be036c32ce2cd19d7671bbc035fed7caac6d7b3a12c46dd62a0108b071d13f063800cb1fa63fea6757a0e7602b801009cd5e8ccf7ab5ff9ec31bd2fe95e14c93d62745118ca4876550dbc4e981ff4172bca409ebc4897c7693b6',
    'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'd13w5pqeg4c45llo4vtnlabi',
    'TS015c37bc': '01bbddaca7c17243e7ff3bfab451bec28e029625ffd3063b1886b41c0850eaa79ed0481ebfed179ade5881442e275df17022147f09e62842b9c6bc513fafccc74d9f3fcb0b3cba5f33f6c1cc6b7c8e70464f33fee6fc8a0df8686f19e2a7dc3751ff8e272e',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
}

data = {
    '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$ucBody$ucContent$ctl00$ddlYear',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
    '__LASTFOCUS': '',
    '__VIEWSTATE': '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',
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': 'B107BC49',
    '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': '',
    'ctl00$ucHeader$txtQuickSearch': '',
    'ctl00$ucBody$ucContent$ctl00$ddlYear': '2021',
}

response = requests.post('https://www.cbi.ir/PolicyRates/policyrates_en.aspx', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,features="html.parser",)
table=soup.find("table",attrs={"class":"table table-hover table-responsive table-condensed table-bordered table-striped"})
div=soup.find("div",attrs={"id":"ctl00_ucBody_ucContent_ctl00_divRates"})

div.tbody
```

prints

```
<tbody>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        12/30/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        21.11
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        20.15
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        12/23/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        21.08
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        20.15
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        12/16/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        21.04
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        20.15
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        12/9/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        21.05
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        20.15
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        12/2/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        21.06
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        20.2
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        11/25/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        21.09
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        20.1
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        11/18/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        20.94
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        19.8
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        11/11/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        20.7
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        19.7
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        11/4/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        20.61
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        19.4
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        10/28/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        20.31
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        19.25
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        10/21/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        19.86
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        19.2
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        10/14/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        19.55
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        19
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        10/7/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        19.47
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        19
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        9/30/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        19.35
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        19
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        9/23/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        19.1
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        -
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        9/16/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        18.74
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        -
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        22
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        14
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="text-align: center">
<td>
                                        9/9/2021
                                    </td>
<td>
                                        18.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I used your code and at first it worked fine but further sending request result in empty div or table tag results saying: "NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'. It seams that the server blocks further requests. So I used other 'User-Agent's and proxies and random 'ASP.NET_SessionId' but none of them worked. Can you modify the code to avoid this?